# android non-clickable notification

Tags: android, notifications

I guess the answer is easy but I still didn't find it. What I need is to set a notification (if the user prefers) to be non-clickable (or not-expandable or whatever it can be called) just as seen at the picture. How can I do it? I thought setting boolean Ongoing to false will be the answer but I was mistaken..

[image: notif]

Comment: I don't know if you can make that happen but I doubt it.

Comment: do you think only system apps can use that kind of notifications? ..would be kinda strange

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't do that. Every `Notification` must have an expandable view (even if it is an empty one). This will give the user a way to cancel the Notification.

And regarding the icons you see (3G, cell towers, ...etc), I believe that OS *and OS only* can set this type of notifications.

Comment: ahm.. are you sure? Actually I have ways to cancel the notification from inside the app which the user can use.

Comment: And if you don't provide those ways to the user?? The system will always give the user a way to cancel, in case your app doesn't.

Comment: didn't catch your thought.. Actually I can create a clickable notification and also don't provide ways to cancel it. Sure it would be a crappy app. I just don't see any reasons why the API don't provide a possiblity of creating a non-clickable notification..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a foreground service.

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
noti.setTicker("");
noti.setContentTitle("");
noti.setContentText("");
noti.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
noti.setOngoing(true);
service.startForeground(11, noti.build());
```

The context I use is the service itself. "11" is the notification id that has to be unique in the application (I think). The Notification.Builder class is from api level 11, but the one in the support library works from api 4. (NotificationCompat.Builder)